# Firestore Security Rules Missing Permissions Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to set up the Cloud Firestore Rules to get back only posts created by the logged in user. When creating a post, I save the user's id as "author_id" in the post document.

I am able to write to the database, but am unable to read with the following security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{post}{
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author_id
    }
    match /friends/{friend=**}{
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have compared the two id's manually and they are the same. 
When I create dummy conditions (which I know should resolve to true), like:

```
allow read: if resource.data.name is string
```

even then I get the same error.

The error I get is as follows:

```
Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (error.js:149)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (serializer.js:93)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (serializer.js:573)
    at PersistentListenStream.onMessage (persistent_stream.js:391)
    at eval (persistent_stream.js:333)
    at eval (persistent_stream.js:308)
    at eval (async_queue.js:83)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4733)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
```

Thank you.

UPDATE:

I came to the realisation that the rules were not filtering the queries and returning back a modified snapshot. I modified my query on the front end to filter the results and things are working now as designed.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *code* that raises that error.

Answer (score 0):

What is the query you use to retrieve the posts?

The result set of the query must comply with the rules. Your query should include a where clause to match the rules:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

ref.where("author_id", "==", user.uid)
```